# Ubuntu 13.04 hangs at purple screen

Tags: 13.04

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 removing my old Windows XP. And now I see that it doesn't go beyond purple screen.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you tell us about your hardware? eg: Model? GPU? CPU? Did it ever boot once?

Comment: Intel CPU 2080 1.73GHz. Dont remember the graphics card. And no it didn't boot even once.

Comment: but the live cd/usb/dvd did?

Comment: Yes. I can boot (Try Ubuntu) via my bootable USB. However while loading i see it says "SRST Failed error no 16"

Comment: does your motherboard's bios let you run the sata controller is AHCI mode? if so try that

Comment: I think there's some issue with Ubuntu 13.04 version as I installed 12.04 and it worked. The only thing is it didn't uninstall 13.04. So every time on first boot, it tries to start with 13.04 and fails. So How can I uninstall 13.04 completely from my machine keeping 12.04?

Comment: you would have to reinstall as there is no downgrade procedure, if recovery mode works you can try [this](https://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater#readme)